# Correct key exchange procedure for hybrid encryption using Pycryptodome

Tags: encryption, python-3.7, pycryptodome, pkcs#1, public-key-exchange

I'm writing a module that creates a secure communication channel using ZeroMQ sockets and [Pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/api.html).

The initial handshake between client and server would follow these steps :

1. Both parties send their *public* RSA key to each other.
2. The server generates an AES session key and a signature for that key.
3. The server RSA-encrypts the session key and the signature before sending it to the client. **(*)**
4. The client verifies the signature and stores the session key.
5. The client generates a token, generates its signature and sends both AES-encrypted to the server.
6. The server verifies the signature and echoes back the token.
7. If the token received matches the one sent, the handshake is considered successful.

I found on [this thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign) that it was preferable to sign the message then encrypt it, rather than encrypting then signing it.

The problem is that the signature, for a 2048 bits RSA key, is 256 bytes long. The maximum encryption size for the same key is 190 bytes. This means I can't encrypt the signature as suggested in the thread.

Should I encrypt the signature with the AES session key ? Should I proceed another way ?

I know there are "standardized" key exchange protocols ([*ECDH*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) for example) but they are not available in Pycryptodome yet.

```
Cipher: RSA PKCS1 OAEP
Signing : PKCS1 PSS w/ BLAKE2b hash
```

Comment: There is a huge problem with your scheme: you need to *trust* the public keys; you cannot just send them. Transport protocols are a different kettle of fish than message signing. It is perfectly possible to encrypt-then-sign in a well designed protocol. Generally I'd say you could simply AES encrypt with a random AES key and then encrypt the AES key (hybrid encryption to get hybrid encryption, yay), but I think there are other things wrong in this scheme; transport protocols are notoriously hard to get right. Hence the most likely response remains: use TLS.

Comment: You mean that the two parties should acquire the other's party public key via a secure and authenticated channel beforehand to ensure that "they are talking to the person they want" ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you have active attacks where an adversary simply replaces the public key with one of his own (MitM attack, for instance). Of course, this is why there is normally a distinction between static authentication key pairs (for which the public key must be trusted) and ephemeral key agreement key pairs.

Comment: I posted the complete handshake procedure. Wouldn't the server's verification of the client signature prevent such attacks ? Looking to it i don't think so... An attacker could generate a signature with his private key that would match the public key he sent.

Comment: Only if the public key of the client can be trusted, otherwise you may be verifying with the public key of the adversary. Your step 1 - exchanging the public keys - is written as part of the protocol, which means to me that it is not part of some out-of-band procedure with steps in place to trust the public keys.

Comment: Indeed it is not. I could implement a password verification, that both parties should know beforehand, and that each would send to the other HMAC-hashed ?

Comment: Read about "pre-shared secret" or PSK. This is becoming more and more a "how to design a transport protocol" territory though :) I'm afraid we need a couple of pages more to get anywhere. I'll just type two things more: `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` . Good luck...

Comment: BLAKE is very cool for hashing a lot of data. I would not use it in a signature used for authentication purposes though. I'd go for compatibility and therefore SHA-256 or SHA-512. Beware of compatibility issues with the hash used for MGF1 in PSS.